# Running tests in a directory parallely in Vitest

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, vitest

I am using `Vitest` as the testing framework for my project.

I have a directory called `canRunInParallel` which contains multiple test files, like `A.spec.ts`, `B.spec.ts` .....  `Z.spec.ts`. Since this directory contains multiple test files, and none of the tests can race condition, I want to configure `Vitest` to run all these tests concurrently, so that I can improve my testing time.

Can anyone help me in figuring out how to achieve the same (by most probably modifying the configuration of Vitest runner)?

Comment: [`test.concurrent`](https://vitest.dev/api/#test-concurrent) or [`describe.concurrent`](https://vitest.dev/api/#describe-concurrent) ?

Comment: They would run all the tests in the given test suite in parallel. What I want is to run multiple test suites parallelly, as each test file in the `canRullInParallel` directory describes a test suite.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not yet supported by `Vitest`.

You can only run the tests in a test suite (test file) concurrently using `Vitest`.

Comment: I certainly see multiple async tests from different test files running at the same time, see "works" and "works": https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1VdE.png I'm using version 0.32.0. What's more - I think it spawns separate processes/forks because my mutex doesn't work and I get race condition (hence my interest in the question...)

Comment: Ended up solving my issue by using proper-lockfile from npm. Hope this helps someone